# Creando block de notas con Tkinter en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, tkinter

qué tal? Soy nuevo en programación, y ahora estoy practicando con interfaces gráficas con Tkinter en Python. Estoy intentando crear un block de notas, y tengo algunas problemas para agregarles funcionalidad al mismo.

Lo que necesito saber es cómo agregarle funcionalidad a los botones de "Cut" (para cortar texto), "Copy" (para copiar texto), "Paste" (para pegar texto), "Find" (para buscar palabras específicas dentro del texto), "Replace" (para buscar y reemplazar palabras dentro del texto), "Save" (para guardar los cambios hechos dentro del texto, que es distinto a 'guardar cómo') y "New File" (para que me abra una nueva ventana donde pueda crear un nuevo texto).

Acá abajo les dejo mi código.

Y una última pregunta, ¿Sería mejor que rehaga todo mi código y lo meta dentro de una clase?

Desde ya gracias, saludos!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st

root=Tk()
root.title("Notepad")

frame=Frame()
frame.pack()

def acerca_de():
    ms.showinfo("About", "Copyright © 2020 Version 1.0")

def licencia():
    ms.showwarning("License", "Notepad \nLICENSE TERMS. \nThese license terms are an agreement between you and Notepad (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates). They apply to the company named above. The terms also apply to any Notepad services or updates for the company, except to the extent those have different terms.")

def update():
    ms.showinfo("Notepad", "There are currently no updates available")

def welcome():
    ms.showinfo("Welcome", "Welcome to the New Notepad")

def salir():
    valor=ms.askquestion("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?")

    if valor =="yes":
        root.destroy()

def cerrar():
    valor = ms.askquestion("Close Window", "Are you sure you want to close it? You will lose all the information.") #true or false

    if valor == "yes":
        root.destroy()


text = st.ScrolledText(frame, font=("Times New Roman", 11))
text.pack()


def abrirArchivo():
    archivo = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=(
        ("Todos los archivos", "*.*"), ("Archivos de Python", "*.py"), ("Archivos de texto", "*.txt")))
    arch1 = open(archivo, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    contenido=arch1.read()
    arch1.close()
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    text.insert("1.0", contenido)

def guardarArchivo():
    
    archivo = fd.asksaveasfilename(title="Save As",  filetypes=(("Archivos de texto", "*.txt"), ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")), defaultextension=".txt")
    arch1=open(archivo, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    arch1.write(text.get("1.0", END))
    arch1.close()
    ms.showinfo("Save As", "The file was correctly saved.")



barraMenu=Menu()
root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)



files=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=files)
files.add_command(label="New File")
files.add_command(label="Open File", command=abrirArchivo)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Save")
files.add_command(label="Save As", command=guardarArchivo)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Close Window", command=cerrar)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Exit", command=salir)


edit=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)
edit.add_command(label="Cut")
edit.add_command(label="Copy")
edit.add_command(label="Paste")
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label="Find")
edit.add_command(label="Replace")


tools=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=tools)
tools.add_command(label="Settings")
tools.add_command(label="Preferences")


helps = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helps)
helps.add_command(label="Welcome", command=welcome)
helps.add_command(label="Documentation")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Report Issue")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="View License",command=licencia)
helps.add_command(label="Privacy Statement")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Chek for Updates", command=update)
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="About", command=acerca_de)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Acá te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo, pero si deseas hacer el `New File`, abriendo una ventana aparte, probablemente, debas crear una clase.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st

path = ""

root = Tk()
root.title("Notepad")

frame = Frame()
frame.pack()


def acerca_de():
    ms.showinfo("About", "Copyright © 2020 Version 1.0")


def licencia():
    ms.showwarning(
        "License",
        "Notepad \nLICENSE TERMS. \nThese license terms are an agreement between you and Notepad (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates). They apply to the company named above. The terms also apply to any Notepad services or updates for the company, except to the extent those have different terms."
    )


def update():
    ms.showinfo("Notepad", "There are currently no updates available")


def welcome():
    ms.showinfo("Welcome", "Welcome to the New Notepad")


def salir():
    valor = ms.askquestion("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?")

    if valor == "yes":
        root.destroy()


def cerrar():
    valor = ms.askquestion("Close Window",
                           "Are you sure you want to close it? You will lose all the information.")  #true or false

    if valor == "yes":
        root.destroy()


text = st.ScrolledText(frame, font=("Times New Roman", 11))
text.pack()


def abrirArchivo():
    global path
    archivo = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File",
                                 filetypes=(("Todos los archivos", "*.*"), ("Archivos de Python", "*.py"),
                                            ("Archivos de texto", "*.txt")))
    arch1 = open(archivo, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    path = arch1.name
    contenido = arch1.read()
    arch1.close()
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    text.insert("1.0", contenido)


def guardarArchivo():
    global path
    archivo = fd.asksaveasfilename(title="Save As",
                                   filetypes=(("Archivos de texto", "*.txt"), ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")),
                                   defaultextension=".txt")
    arch1 = open(archivo, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    path = arch1.name
    arch1.write(text.get("1.0", END))
    arch1.close()
    ms.showinfo("Save As", "The file was correctly saved.")


def cut():
    text.clipboard_clear()
    text.clipboard_append(text.selection_get())
    text.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")


def copy():
    text.clipboard_clear()
    text.clipboard_append(text.selection_get())


def paste():
    text.insert(INSERT, text.clipboard_get())


def save():
    if path != "":
        contenido = text.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
        archivo = open(path, 'w+')
        archivo.write(contenido)
        archivo.close()
        ms.showinfo("Confirmación", "Archivo guardado correctamente")
    else:
        guardarArchivo()


def newFile():
    global path
    path = ""
    text.delete(1.0, END)


entry_find = Entry(frame)


def find1():
    text.tag_remove('found', '1.0', END)
    s = entry_find.get()
    if (s):
        index = '1.0'
        while 1:
            index = text.search(s, index, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            if not index:
                break
            lastindex = '% s+% dc' % (index, len(s))
            text.tag_add('found', index, lastindex)
            index = lastindex
        text.tag_config('found', foreground='red')
    entry_find.focus_set()


find_btn = Button(frame, text='Buscar', command=find1)


def closeSearch():
    close_find.pack_forget()
    find_btn.pack_forget()
    entry_find.pack_forget()
    close_replace.pack_forget()
    entry_replace.pack_forget()
    replace_btn.pack_forget()


close_find = Button(frame, text='x', command=closeSearch)


def find():
    close_find.pack(side=LEFT)
    entry_find.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    entry_find.focus_set()
    find_btn.pack(side=LEFT)


entry_replace = Entry(frame)


def replace1():
    text.tag_remove('found', '1.0', END)
    s = entry_find.get()
    r = entry_replace.get()

    if (s and r):
        index = '1.0'
        while 1:
            index = text.search(s, index, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            if not index:
                break
            lastindex = '% s+% dc' % (index, len(s))
            text.delete(index, lastindex)
            text.insert(index, r)
            lastindex = '% s+% dc' % (index, len(r))
            text.tag_add('found', index, lastindex)
            index = lastindex
        text.tag_config('found', foreground='green', background='yellow')
    entry_find.focus_set()


replace_btn = Button(frame, text='Reemplazar', command=replace1)


def closeReplace():
    close_replace.pack_forget()
    entry_replace.pack_forget()
    replace_btn.pack_forget()


close_replace = Button(frame, text='x', command=closeReplace)


def replace():
    find()
    close_replace.pack(side=LEFT)
    entry_replace.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    entry_replace.focus_set()
    replace_btn.pack(side=LEFT)


barraMenu = Menu()
root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)

files = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=files)
files.add_command(label="New File", command=newFile)
files.add_command(label="Open File", command=abrirArchivo)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Save", command=save)
files.add_command(label="Save As", command=guardarArchivo)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Close Window", command=cerrar)
files.add_separator()
files.add_command(label="Exit", command=salir)

edit = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)
edit.add_command(label="Cut", command=cut)
edit.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)
edit.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste)
edit.add_separator()
edit.add_command(label="Find", command=find)
edit.add_command(label="Replace", command=replace)

tools = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=tools)
tools.add_command(label="Settings")
tools.add_command(label="Preferences")

helps = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helps)
helps.add_command(label="Welcome", command=welcome)
helps.add_command(label="Documentation")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Report Issue")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="View License", command=licencia)
helps.add_command(label="Privacy Statement")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Chek for Updates", command=update)
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="About", command=acerca_de)

root.mainloop()
```

La variable `path` te permitirá almacenar la ruta del fichero, por tanto, cuando se ejecuten los métodos `newFile`, `abrirArchivo` y `guardarArchivo`, esta debe ser actualizada.

Para cortar texto se utiliza el método `cut`.

Para copiar texto se utiliza el método `copy`.

Para pegar texto: `paste`.

Para guardar los cambios hechos dentro del texto: `save`. Para este método, primero se verifica que exista una ruta definida para el archivo y te permite guardar los cambios, si no existe, se llama al método que tienes hecho para `guardarArchivo` que te permitirá crear un archivo nuevo con el texto.

El método `newFile`, no está concebido para abrir una nueva ventana, sino para editar en la misma ventana que ya tenías (como si fuera nueva).

Para buscar palabras específicas dentro del texto: `find`. Este método permite, que al seleccionar `Find`, se muestre en la parte inferior del editor: un botón para cancelar la búsqueda, un Entry para ingresar el texto que deseas buscar y el botón para ejercer la búsqueda. El botón de cancelar, ejecuta el método `closeSearch` que permite remover los widgets de la ventana (sin destruirlos), referentes a la búsqueda y el reemplazo. Al dar clic en el botón de ejercer la búsqueda, se ejecuta el método `find1`, que señala todas las ocurrencias del texto, cambiando su color a rojo.

Para buscar y reemplazar palabras dentro del texto: `replace`. Este método permite, que al seleccionar `Replace`, se muestre en la parte inferior del editor: todo lo referente a buscar (si no se estaba mostrando), un botón para cancelar, un Entry para ingresar el texto por el que deseas reemplazar lo que tienes puesto en el Entry de buscar y el botón para ejercer el reemplazo. El botón de cancelar, ejecuta el método `closeReplace` que permite remover los widgets de la ventana (sin destruirlos), referentes sólo al reemplazo (no incluye los de la búsqueda). Al dar clic en el botón de ejercer el reemplazo, se ejecuta el método `replace1`, que reemplaza todas las ocurrencias del texto que se encuentra en el Entry de buscar por el del Entry del reemplazo, señalándolo con un color verde y un color de fondo a amarillo.

Comment: Sos un geni@ Firefly,  no conocía el módulo de cleo, te agradezco muchísimo, saludos!